# Why it takes so long to download PDF file from google drive in android?

Tags: android, performance, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to download PDF file from google drive using the code below:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                Log.v(TAG,"server returned http " + urlConnection.getResponseCode()
                        + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }
            else{
                Log.v(TAG + "downloading" ,"server returned http " + urlConnection.getResponseCode()
                        + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            int total = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))!= -1 ) 
            {
                i+=1;
                Log.v(TAG + "downloading","downloading mega #"+i);
                total += bufferLength;
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

as shown in the code, each iteration in the while loop downloads one mega, but it takes **2650 iteration** to download only 2 mega file !!!!!! 
Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly say, why it's happening, but quoting the javadoc [Inputstream#read(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])):

> The number of bytes read is, **at most**, equal to the length of b.

(Emphasis added by me)

Possible reasons why expectations don't meet reality here:

- `MEGABYTE` is set to the wrong size (should be 1000000)
- the connection speed is not high enough
- other hindrances, 'read' can't read the full buffer size per loop

You could check the amount of bytes read per loop, but it probably won't help you that much.

Comment: - I defined MEGABYTE to equal 1024 * 1024 
- when i download it from the normal browser it takes faster so I don't think it is a connection speed problem
- it actually may be that 'read' can't read the full buffer size per loop. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Oh okay, that definition works too. No, sadly I don't know how to solve this. Does it take a longer time to download too compared to the browser download?